# Calculating the resultant of two forces and angle?

Tags: trigonometry, physics

A force of $256 N$ and a vertical load of $537 N$. Trying to work out the resultant of the two forces and the angle at which it acts to the horizontal?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you please clarify your question, I think we are lacking information here. In what direction does the force act?

Comment: The only information I have is that (A parting tool is fed into a work piece, in this case a component for a vehicle, with a force of 256N and the vertical load on the tool tip is 537N. Attempting to calculate the resultant of the two forces and the angel at which it acts to the horizontal.

Comment: Looks to be solved

Comment: This is what we have worked out, in the end we calculated it as 537N as 90 degrees and 256N at 0 degrees, the question was from a college assignment which was poorly written and since scrapped.
R² = 537² + 256²
= 353905
R = 594.9N

tan(theta)=opposite/adjacent
tan(theta)=(537/256)
theta=tan^-1(537/256)
theta=64.512 degrees above horizontal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

The resultant ($R$) of any two forces say $P$ & $Q$ having angle $\alpha$ between them is given as $$R=\sqrt{P^2+Q^2+2PQ\cos \alpha}$$

The acute angle $\theta$ between the resultant & the force $P$  is given as 
$$\theta=\tan^{-1}\left|\frac{Q\sin \alpha}{P+Q\cos \alpha}\right|$$